# Flutter app cannot run when sqflite dependency is added - Execution failed for task ':sqflite:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, riverpod, sqflite

The app doesn't run when I add the `sqflite` dependency to my flutter project. It shows the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\theak\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\theak\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
```

This is the dependency that I have added to my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.10
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
```

Here is my `flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.87.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Also, I am using `riverpod` for the first time, which may be the problem here. Here's my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/screens/add_task_page.dart';
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/screens/edit_task_page.dart';
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/screens/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/todos_notifier.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final todosProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TodosNotifier, TodosState>((ref) => TodosNotifier());

//Colors
Color blackColor = const Color(0xff0c120c);
Color blueColor = const Color(0xff4285F4);
Color whiteColor = const Color(0xffFDFDFF);
Color iconColor = const Color(0xff565656);
Color outlineColor = const Color(0xffD6D6D6);
Color descriptionColor = const Color(0xff565656);

void main() {
  //status bar & navigation bar colors and themes
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: whiteColor,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarColor: whiteColor,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: whiteColor));

  //Riverpod globally enabled
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: DoableApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class DoableApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DoableApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          //colors
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          focusColor: Colors.transparent,
          hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
          //font family
          fontFamily: "Inter",
          textTheme: const TextTheme(
            //Main heading font style - "Create to-do, Modify to-do"
            displayLarge: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                color: Color(0xff0c120c)),
            //Subheading font style - "Today, Settings"
            displayMedium: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Color(0xff0c120c)),
            //Regular app font style - "Set Reminder, Daily, Save, License, ..."
            displaySmall: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Color(0xff0c120c)),
            //box heading font style - "Tell us about your task, Date & Time, Completion status, ..."
            labelSmall: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Color(0xff565656)),
            //Task list heading font style - "Return Library Book"
            bodyLarge: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Color(0xff0c120c)),
            //Task list description font style - "Gather overdue library books and return..."
            bodyMedium: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Color(0xff565656)),
            //Task list icon text font style - "11:30 AM, 26/11/24"
            bodySmall: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                color: Color(0xff565656)),
          )),

      //routes
      initialRoute: 'home',
      routes: {
        'home': (context) => const HomePage(),
        'add_task': (context) => const AddTaskPage(),
        'edit_task': (context) => const EditTaskPage(),
        'settings': (context) => const SettingsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

double verticalPadding(BuildContext context) {
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20;
}

double horizontalPadding(BuildContext context) {
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20;
}

EdgeInsets textFieldPadding(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: Convert 25px into respected MediaQuery size
  return EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
      vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025);
}
```

This is my `edit_task_page.dart` file which I haven't even started coding (still error):

```
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:doable_todo_list_app/todos_notifier.dart';

class EditTaskPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const EditTaskPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final todos = ref.watch(todosProvider);

    return const Scaffold();
  }
}
```